# Unable to obtain long-lived token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have reported a `bug` about this (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/163942813778219).

I have implemented the server-side login flow which is supposed to result a long-lived user acess_token.

I have two cases where I am not able to obtain the long-lived token; the process runs properly though it results a short-lived token.

One case is a general profile; the other one is a profile migrated into Page only.

In all other tested cases it works properly, resulting a long-lived token, as expected.

Still, after I get the unexpected short-lived token, I will try to exchange it for a long-lived by using the specific endpoint for this purpose. What I get as result is a different new token but still with the same short expiration time.

Important to mention: I am able to generate the long-lived access_token for these two cases by using an different application ID.

Does any one have any thoughts on this?